# Getting 404 error while calling controller action method by using ajax in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, calling an action method inside a controller by using Ajax. This Ajax call is inside a separate JS file called site.js. On a button click am calling this Ajax. Everything is working on local. But when I deploy my project on IIS am getting a 404 error while calling that action method on Ajax.

Index.cshtml

```
<form id="submitForm">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

SalesController.cs

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<T> GetAll() {
    }
}
```

site.js

```
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", (event) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Sales/GetAll",
        type: "POST",
        success: async () => {
        },
        error: () => {
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: This could happen if your site has not been deployed to the *root* folder.  eg, if your local is `http://localhost/page` but server is `http://server/site/page`.   That's what `@Url.Action` is for - so you don't hardcode paths into your js - of course, your js is in its own `script.js` so won't be parsed server-side (so can't use `@Url`).   What is the page's url on your local vs the server?

Comment: What does the URL look like in your local running environment and the deployed URL?